# Saving data from facebook graph api in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im building a tool that tracks data from the facebook graph api. One of the things I want to save is the countrys where a page get his likes from per day. The graph api returns this in the following format:

```
"value": {
   "AE": 6884,
   "AU": 19239,
   "BD": 4565,
   "BE": 2301,
   "ZA": 5432
}
```

Now I want to save this in a mysql table.

Option 1 is to add al countrys as a row in my table so that would look something like

```
date | country1 | country2 | country3 | etc
```

Now this option would be fine but there are a lot of countrys so I have to add all countrys. Somehow this just doesnt feel right.

Option 2 would to be to store the complete json data in 1 column, so:

```
date | value
```

But ofcourse this would remove a lot of functionality from mysql that we have to handle somewhere else (in php or javascript) so it would be a lot slower.

Are there any other options that I should consider? MongoDB is not really an option since the system is already build in lamp.

Comment: `date | country | value`

Comment: Would that be better than date | country1 | etc | since it will preduce a lot of rows

Comment: Databases are meant to handle a lot of rows. And this is simply called normalization - go read up on that keyword, if it is news to you. And the argument for why you do not want to go with `country1 | country 2 | ...` is simple - what if a new country gets added at some point? Do you want to change your table structure and the code that accesses the data every single time that happens - or do you just want to add another row, which when you are already looping over the input data requires no change whatsoever …?

Comment: Oke yeah, that makes a lot of sence! thanks for the help!